# Banach spaces isomorphic to square

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This is another exercise from Allan's book "Introduction to Banach Spaces and Algebras".

> Exercise 2.9: A Banach space $E$ is said to be *homeomorphic to its square* if $E\oplus E$ is linearly homeomorphic to $E$.  Prove that the spaces $c$ and $C([0,1])$ have this property.

Note that we haven't developed much theory yet (in this book!)  Well, $c_0 \oplus c_0 \cong c_0$ (split a sequence into the parts supported on the evens and odds say) and $c\cong c_0$, so that does the case of $c$.  I cannot see an elementary proof for $C([0,1])$.  Here's a less than easy proof: clearly $C([0,1]) \oplus_\infty C([0,1]) = C([0,1] \cup [2,3])$ say.  Then appeal to Miljutin's Theorem, as $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is an uncountable compact metric space, $C([0,1] \cup [2,3]) \cong C([0,1])$.

Surely I don't need the full power of Miljutin's Theorem.  But, for example, $C([0,1] \cup [2,3])$ cannot be *isometric* to $C([0,1])$ (if we use real scalars) by the Banach-Stone theorem, as $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Surely using Miljutin's Theorem is not what the book intends.

> Is there an elementary proof that $C([0,1]) \oplus C([0,1]) \cong C([0,1])$?

Comment: Perhaps this is a start: Let $T:C([0,1])\oplus C([0,1])\to C([0,1])\oplus \mathbb R$ be defined by $T(f,g)=(h(t),g(0))$ where 
$$h(t)=\begin{cases} f(2t) &\mbox{if } t \leq 1/2 \\ 
g(2t-1)+f(1)-g(0) & \mbox{if } t>1/2 \end{cases} $$
and note that $h$ is continuous as $h(1/2)=f(1)=g(1)+f(1)-g(1)$.

Comment: This was known to Banach, and is in his book; see Theorem 6 and Theorem 8 on p.111 on the English language translation of the book.

Comment: @PhilipBrooker Could you give a reference?

Comment: @Phil: Indeed!  That certainly counts as "elementary".  But it does seem a stretch that someone could think of this on their own... So now I do wonder if the exercise was set erroneously.  If you want to make that into an answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: @Matt: Does it really say "homeomorphic to it square" rather than "isomorphic to its square" in Allan's book? I only just noticed that wording in your question, and it is obviously strange because all separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic to one another...

Comment: @Phil: I think you missed that it's "_linearly_ homeomorphic".  But, yes, I too would usually say "isomorphic" for this...

Comment: @Matt: Hmmm... I think it is silly to preface the first occurrence of the word *homeomorphic* in the above definition with the word *linear*, but not the second occurrence. Of course, I too am all for using the word isomorphic except (sometimes) when explaining things to non-specialists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Reposting my comment from above:) This result was known to Banach and a proof can be found in his book *Theory of Linear Operations* (note that this is the English translation of the French original); for details see Theorems 6 and 8 on p.111.

To give a little more information here, Theorem 6 from Banach's book asserts that $C([0,1])$ is isomorphic to $C([0,1])\oplus c_0$, whilst Theorem 8 from the same book shows similar to Alex Becker's comment above that $C([0,1])\oplus C([0,1])$ is isomorphic to $C([0,1])\oplus \mathbb{R}$. One then deduces that $$C([0,1])\oplus C([0,1]) \approx C([0,1])\oplus \mathbb{R}\approx (C([0,1])\oplus c_0) \oplus \mathbb{R} $$ $$\approx C([0,1])\oplus (c_0 \oplus \mathbb{R}) \approx C([0,1])\oplus c_0 \approx C([0,1]).$$

As Matt points out in the comments above, coming up with and executing this strategy seems a little heavy for an exercise!

Comment: Thanks!  That'll nicely move your reputation up from "666"... ;->

Comment: Haha! Thanks Matt. I answered a question yesterday but even then got no votes for my answer, so I was stuck on that particular score for a while :-) . Thanks again for 'saving' me!